# How to join multiple models and get the result in pythonic way?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, sqlite

I have 4 models.

```
class User(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField()

class Subscription(models.Model):
  user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
  title = models.CharField()

class Address(models.Model):
  user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
  street  = models.CharField()

class Wallet(models.Model):
  user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
  balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Here I want to get the subscription rows along with the respected user address and wallet balance. Is that possible to retrieve in a single query (ORM)?

I heard about *select_related()* and *prefetch_related()*. But not sure how to put all together in a single queryset.

How can I achieve this in pythonic way?

Comment: Something like this? `User.objects.filter(id=?).select_related('subscription', 'address', 'wallet')`

Comment: There's no reference for subscription, address and wallet in user table. Above fields are the only available fields in the table. :(

Comment: can you update your question with your full models.py?

Comment: No time to test right now, but this can be done with serializers, `serializers.serialize('python', User.objects.get(id=?), fields=('id', 'name', 'subscription__set__user_id', 'subscription__set__title, '...'))` Post your models.py it will be more helpfull

Comment: @Mojimi it doesn't sound like he actually has foreign keys set up between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `_id` from FK fields. You'll still have `subscription.user_id` (int) and `subscription.user` which is `User`. Right now you have to write `subscription.user_id_id` for accessing id.

Do you understand that user can have multiple wallets and addresses with you db design?

It is not possible to do it in a single query with ORM. But it is possible to do it in 3 queries (doesn't matter how many records).

**UPDATED:**

```
class User(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

class Subscription(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='subscriptions')
      title = models.CharField()

class Address(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='addresses')
      street  = models.CharField()

class Wallet(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='wallets')
      balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)


subscriptions = Subscription.objects.select_related('user').prefetch_related(
                    'user__wallets', 'user__addresses')

for s in subscriptions:
    print(s.user.name)
    for wallet in s.user.wallets.all():
        print(wallet.balance)
    for address in s.user.addresses.all():
        print(address.street)
```

Comment: If user should have just one wallet and address than move FKs to User model and retrieve everything with one query using `select_related`.

Comment: Cannot find 'wallet_set' on User object, 'user__wallet_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related(). 
There's no reference to Wallet from User model. I've only the reference to User model from Wallet model.
Thanks for notifying the "_id" and multiple wallet for one user.
But my core problem still exists :(

Comment: `<lowercased_model_name>_set` is the default `related_name` for ForeignKeys. But I prefer to specify it implicitly as I did it now. Check it.

Comment: May be it didn't work because you didn't update your models. With your models it should be `.prefetch_related('user_id__wallet_set', 'user_id__address_set')`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow [this snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) from documentation?

Having a `User` object instance you can do something like this to access subscriptions:

```
user.subscription_set.all()
```

It will require separate calls to different managers to collect all your data though.